# What is a USB Device GUID and What does it mean

Tags: windows, usb, guid

See this Registry key:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties\PrivateProperties\DirectInput\VID_0079&PID_0011\Calibration\0]
   "GUID"=hex:e0,fa,66,14,00,b3,e0,11,80,01,44,45,53,54,00,00

As you can see there is a GUID key for this Device, and it contains some Hex codes. I want to know what is GUID and what does it mean really, which info does it give me and any other important info about it.

Any Help Really Appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to ask DragonRise Inc. It's their gamepad. There is no global overarching documentation for the data that each individual company stores in the registry.

Comment: Thanks, But can you tell me what is GUID exactly totally? and what kind of dada it stores regularly? The above registry key is just an example.

Comment: A GUID is a "Globally Unique Identifier", a 128 bit number. It doesn't store any information; it's purpose is only to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've been able to dig up in various locations, you are looking at a Device GUID

> The term JoystickGUID is a stable 128-bit identifier for a joystick
>   device that does not change over time, it identifies class of the
>   device (a X360 wired controller for example). This identifier is
>   platform dependent.

Looking at other references gives a bit more information, [Joystick:getGUID](https://love2d.org/wiki/Joystick:getGUID)